# Redmine How to upload and download file inside plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am trying to create Redmine plugin and in that plugin i want to upload file or image and also display image or download file on show action. can anyone help me.

**In Model**

```
class UserInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  unloadable
  belongs_to :project

  acts_as_attachable :view_permission => :view_files,
                    :edit_permission => :manage_files,
                    :delete_permission => :manage_files
```

**In Controller**

```
    class UserInformationsController < ApplicationController
      unloadable
      require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../../../app/helpers/attachments_helper'
        include AttachmentsHelper
        helper :attachments
```

**In new.html.erb**

```
        <p> <%= render :partial => 'attachments/form' %></p>
```

**In show.html.erb**

```
    <%= link_to_attachments @info, :thumbnails => true %>
```

Can you help me is it correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redmine already has classes for work with attachments - model `Attachment`, controller `AttachmentsController` and attachments views and helpers.

You can use them in your own classes.

Add `acts_as_attachable...` with neccesary options to your model class after `unloadable` row. Options are:

- Permission options. Eg `:view_permission => :view_attachments_permissions`, where `view_attachments_permissions` is standard or plugin permission. If user wants to download attachments, he must have role with that permission, or that permission must be public (only plugin permissions - public option sets in source code).
- Behavior options (actions after adding, removing, etc).
- And perhaps other options.

Add `<%= render :partial => 'attachments/form' %>` in your views.

And call `save_attachments` method in your controller when it saves your model instance.
Or add attachments manually after instance saved:

```
params[:attachments].each do |attachment_param|
    attachment = Attachment.where('filename = ?', attachment_param[1][:filename]).first
    unless attachment.nil?
        attachment.container_type = YourModel.name
        attachment.container_id = set.id
        attachment.save
    end
end
```

Attachments saves immediately after adding, but without container info

---

Also You can add attachments to existing redmine class via patching.

For example, I patched `TimeEntry` class:

```
require_dependency 'time_entry'

  module TimeEntryPatch

  def self.included(base) # :nodoc:
      base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)

      base.class_eval do
          unloadable # Send unloadable so it will not be unloaded in development
          acts_as_attachable :after_add => :attachment_added, :after_remove => :attachment_removed
      end
  end
...
```

---

You can look examples directly in Redmine code.

Attachments are used by `issue`, `Project` and some other models.
I found answers for my questions there!

---

For view attached images You can use plugins like [Lightbox 2](https://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_lightbox2).
Add plugin to your Redmine or copy its code and stylesheets to your plugin.

Comment: WOW Thats work for me.now I am able to upload the file but how to download file. i am facing error You are not authorized to access this page. see now i am added model code as per you suggest

Comment: I added attachments recently, and still have same error too

I haven't yet figured out, but most likely it resolved by editing permissions in ```init.rb``` file:


    ...

    project_module :your_plugin do

      permission :permission_name, {:your_model => [:actions_array]},  :public => true

    end

    ....


look http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial#Adding-new-permissions

Comment: facing same issue after add init permission.

Comment: I understood!
In ```acts_as_attachable``` row you must add permissions that your current role have.
I added my public permission
acts_as_attachable :view_permission => :attachments_sets, :delete_permission => :attachments_sets
and now can download my attachments!

In your code sample you must have :view_files permission to download attachments

Comment: Where is mention permission I just copied this permission from project model..please help me?

Comment: If you are use standart permissions (from project), you need not write any more code, set this permissions to some role and give that role to your user in work project
If you want your own permission, add it to init.rb, like me:
permission :attachments_sets, {:attachments_sets => [:edit]}, :public => true
and use it in model:
acts_as_attachable :view_permission => :attachments_sets, :delete_permission => :attachments_sets

Answer (score 0):

I've done that in this plugin: https://github.com/iridakos/release_logs. Check the related code.